# Discrepancies in fetches

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We noticed a discrepancy in the number of rows in fetches for the same date range.
Further investigation showed that these 2 video ids (-dz0zZV5MyQ, 8GQl03jq50c) that Youtube Analytics API doesn’t return all video available. Please check out my findings:

Before calling the report query first of all we fetch all uploaded videos for a given channel.

For fetching all uploaded video we use following endpoints:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

**Endpoints execution (endpoint name + parameters sent)**:
endpoint channels {'id': 'UC-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'contentDetails', 'maxResults': 50} → get playlistid from here and use in the next calls
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaBlBUOkNESQ'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaBlBUOkNHUQ'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNKWUI'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNNZ0I'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNQb0I'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNLd0M'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNONEM'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNKQUQ'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNNSUQ'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNQUUQ'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNLWUU'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNOZ0U'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNJb0Y'}
endpoint playlistItems {'playlistId': 'UU-vFz_g0XCKqAJ4ckgx6ZoQ', 'part': 'snippet', 'maxResults': 50, 'pageToken': 'EAAaB1BUOkNMd0Y'}

Can you help?

We found that these videos actually exist, for ex:

- vUKbPBLGaGw → Produkttrainer erklärt: Schnittschutz
- 4jZo1myDNwo → TIMBERSPORTS® Faszination Sportholzfällen - Damen
- Xd9jwEtLZJU → STIHL Check: 3/8" Rapid Hexa | Hochleistungs-Sägekette mit innovativer Zahnform

Comment: check the bug reports this api is not accurate at all.

Comment: where can I see the bug reports @LindaLawton-DaImTo?

Comment: [bug central](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)